# Select by location features that “mostly” don’t overlap with another layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-location

I have annual polygon layers that for some reason contain polygon features that are supposed to be identical (represent the same plot and contract), but are very slightly different (vertices are often barely off). I received them this way, and there is no way for me to get them in a more precise fashion.

Starting with the most recent layer (2020 in my case) I need to merge polygons from earlier years that mostly don’t overlap with the 2020 layer. I will do this starting with a 2019 layer, and then continue to work my way backwards until I have incorporated all of the years’ data into a single layer (this will end up being about 300k small polygons). Essentially, iterate through selecting polygons that represent unique plot/contracts from older years and merging them with the 2020 layer.There is no unique identifier in the attribute table, so using any sort of attribute won't help.

It is simple for me to get all of the disjoint polygons by inverting an intersecting selection (see below). However, I haven’t figured out a way to get at the purple 2019 polys that touch/barely overlap the peach 2020 polys. I have tried many of the other spatial relationships and adding and subtracting to/from smaller or larger selections, but haven’t been able to get what I want. Because of the irregular shape of these polygons, “have their center in” doesn’t work as accurately as I would like.

This is using ArcGIS Pro, but I’m open to solutions from Qgis, and Python or R libraries.

[image: Select by location: inverted intersect]

Comment: When you say there is no way to get them more precise is that because of some directive you have to follow?  If it was just a GIS issue and the vertices are just slightly different you could try the Integrate tool,  Snap tool or use a topology with a tolerance and validate it to  "clean" the layers up.  If the only problem year was 2019 you could use the Feature to Point tool with the keep point within the polygon option, run your selection on the points use those to select your polygons and see how that works.  For the rare case of a point within a tolerance of an edge, do a manual selection.

Comment: Intersect old and new. Summarise area by old_fid, join this table to old. If sum_area is NULL or below small threshold, old polygon is mostly outside

Comment: @John There are unfortunately a few hundred thousand polygons, and I don't think I want to do any of this manually. Is the snap tool an automated process?

Comment: @FelixIP I think this could work, I will try that